# Wingpanel guest session disappears

Tags: wingpanel, camera

Wingpanel on guest session disappears when clicked. It seems that the issue has something to do with apps installed through snap even though the target file has chmod 755 permission. Any clue on how to solve it?

```
** (wingpanel:26863): WARNING **: 20:41:27.288: AsyncImage.vala:384: Error opening file /snap/postman/108/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/assets/icon.png: Permission denied

** Message: 20:41:27.299: DBusService.vala:64: Service registration suceeded

** (wingpanel:26863): WARNING **: 20:41:27.445: desktop-file-service.vala:117: ubuntu is not understood

** (wingpanel:26863): ERROR **: 20:41:27.566: worker-link.vala:83: Failed to create D-Bus server: Error binding to address: Permission denied
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Apparmor is blocking the bind of a unix-socket at /tmp/

You can whitelist that by adding the following line to `/etc/apparmor.d/lightdm-guest-session`:

```
unix (bind, listen) type=stream addr="@/tmp/applications-menu-*",
```